# How does Anki store flashcard and remind it at a certain amount of time?

Tags: store, anki

I wonder how can Anki (a flash card application to help people memorize things) store the cards in a file (including images and audio) and retrieve them at a certain amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

it is using sqllite database. you can check source code of anki app... take look to test folder on github
https://github.com/dae/anki/blob/master/tests/test_collection.py